# Plot pairs of solutions to non-linear equation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I tried to plot pairs (x,y) which are solutions to the equation  y^2 + y = x^3 + y(x^2) using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.arange(0,12,.01)
x = np.arange(0,18,.01)
for i in enumerate(y):
    for j in enumerate(x):
        if (i**2)+i == j**3 + i*(j**2):
            plot(i,j)
```

However, I got the following error:
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'"

Anybody can help me to figure out how can I plot solutions?

I have also another question: Is it possible to store each pair of solution in a variable so we can use specific pairs of solutions in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you modify your formulation and plot the square difference between LHS and RHS instead:

```
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

def F(p):
    x, y = p
    v = y**2 + y - x**3 - y * (x**2)
    return v**2

Z = F((X, Y))
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)
plt.colorbar()
idx = np.where(np.abs(Z) < 1e-4)
plt.scatter(X[idx], Y[idx], marker='+', color='w')
```

[image]

You can also use `scipy.optimize.fmin(F, [1, 1])` to get the exact solution of `F=0`, where `[1, 1]` is your initial guess.  In this case, different initial guess will result in different solution.

Comment: Thank you so much @CT Zhu. That's the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`enumerate` yields `(index, value)` tuples, you can use unpacking to get each one separately in the loop header:

```
for i_ind, i in enumerate(y):
    for j_ind, j in enumerate(x):
```

Comment: Thanks @MrGeek for the reply. Do I need to replace i and j in the equation with i_val and j_val?

Comment: @shirinelahi You can rename the variables to whatever you want, what matters is that the order is `(index, value)`.

Answer (score 1):

while the other answer describes the mechanical transform needed to stop that exception being thrown, it's not going to get any points in your plot.  Numpy is a numeric library, while you want/need to solve the equation.

`numpy.arange(0, 12, 0.01)` generates a **finite** series of numbers starting at 0 and incrementing by 0.01 until it hits 12.  you give an equation above which is mostly translated into Python code, and evaluate it on these finite series of numbers and ask it to plot values where both expressions evaluate to the same number.  floats in Python are [64-bit floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) so this equality is checked to approx 15 decimal digits, which will basically not happen for your numbers.

instead of doing what you're attempting to do you want to use something like [Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html) which would actually help you.  to get started we do:

```
from sympy import symbols, solveset, simplify, lambdify

x, y = symbols('x y')

eq1 = y**2 + y
eq2 = x**3 + x*y**2

ss = solveset(eq1 - eq2, y)
```

which names a pair of symbols, puts them into some equations and [solves](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html) for when `eq1 == eq2` (equivalently when their difference is zero).

next you want to plot these solutions, which can be done in this case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx = np.linspace(-5, 4, 101)
for eq in ss:
    fn = lambdify(x, eq)
    yy = fn(xx)
    # hide complex solutions
    yy[~np.isreal(yy)] = np.nan
    plt.plot(xx, np.real(yy), label=simplify(eq))

plt.legend()
```

this starts by pulling in numpy and matplotlib, then sampling points on the x-axis at which we want to evaluate the functions, then loop through solutions turning them into Python functions that we can evaluate to get numeric answers, next we evaluate this on our sampled points, discard complex solutions, and plot the results.

this gives:

[image: plot of solutions]

the gap around `x = -4.5` is due to sampling at this point being sparse.  we can check by evaluating our equations at `x=-4.5, y=10`, and I get ~110 for both equations

Comment: Thank you so much Sam for your comprehensive explanation.